# Android Studio doesn't find com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0

Tags: java, android, sdk, android-studio

I have imported one project into `Android Studio` but I got the error:

> Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0.

Where could I find this file? I have imported the project using `Gradle`.

I have the `Android Studio version 0.5.7` the last android sdk and `java 1.7u55`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add this code to you **build.gradle** file

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
}
```

and press *Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files*

Gradle will download necessary files by himself

Comment: where exactly to add this?

Comment: No such property: compile for class: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler

Comment: In The SDK Manager, I had to install the Android Support Repository AND the Android Support Library.

Answer (score 2):

It does not work for me either. It works with 19.0.1
But if (I use gradle) I do this in my build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    def androidHome = System.getenv("ANDROID_HOME")
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "$androidHome/extras/android/m2repository/"
    }
}
```

It finds the artifact.

Comment: I also found the root cause.
If I use classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.1' it does not work, but if I use
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.1'
it works.

Answer (score 2):

From the SDK Manager, delete and re-install the Android Support Library 19.1 package.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem with morning. I found the Jar file that I needed in `/<MySdkFolder>/extras/android/support/` - in there are some sub folders with the different support libraries in them, so the last part of the path depends on which one that you want to use.

I just copied this into the lib folder of the project. I'm sure there is a more technical solution but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Right clicking on the library and select the import as library option from the context menu works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Following theory works at me:

Android Studio has problems importing support-v4:19.1.+ library when it comes through a transitive  dependency.

Solution Adding support-v4 as own dependency and exclude this lib where it comes transitive. then i could not more see this import issue

Answer (score 0):

Try to go

> Project Structure -> Dependencies -> Add : then select -> File
>   dependecies

then  select the proper library

Answer (score 0):

This artifact is available on [google maven repository](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=support-v4#com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0). So need to add following in the build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. This line to build.gradle works -->
implementation 'com.android.support:support v4:28.0.0'